# Redux DevTools in office addin

Tags: angular, ngrx, excel-addins, redux-devtools

I'm working on an Excel add-in that uses angular 15, in the angular app, I've just added @ngrx/store. I've added the dev tools to the module as well. I noticed that Excel uses Edge to run the add-in. However, I've installed redux dev tools for Edge, and they do not show up inside the Excel add-in. Does anyone know how to show the redux dev tools in an Excel add-in?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to use the remove version of DevTools, https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-devtools/tree/main/packages/redux-devtools-remote